# How can I troubleshoot VENVs `--system-site-packages` not mirroring my system?

Tags: python, arch-linux, virtualenv

I'm running Arch Linux and want to use virtual environments to install only those few PIP packages I use for specific projects while continuing to use the Arch packages for Python. However, when I make a new VENV that uses the `--system-site-packages` argument (for accessing the Arch base Python packages), the new VENV isn't a complete mirror of the non-VENV environment.

How I tested this:

1. `pip freeze` of my current install of [Python from Arch packages](https://pastebin.com/meaUx6AN).
2. Created a virtual environment, venv
   `$mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages venv`
3. Created a second `pip freeze` from [inside the active venv](https://pastebin.com/3ytmPFPE)
4. [Compare using `diff`](https://pastebin.com/v0Nvr8CQ)

I expected the diff to be the same, but there are numerous differences.

I believe all the Python and related packages were [installed with `pacman`](https://pastebin.com/0K4pGRLv). I'm positive all the major packages (iPython, Numpy, Pandas, Jupyter, Matplotlib, etc.) were installed with Arch's package manager `pacman`. Since I didn't just install my system yesterday, it's certainly *possible*, over time, that I've used PIP for a few packages, but the rule I've followed is to use the `pacman` installed packages to take advantage of the Arch community fixing incompatibilities (opposed to some combination of Github, PiP, and Arch packages).

How can I troubleshoot the problem of different packages in my VENV using the `--system-site-packages` argument?

---

NOTE. This question might be going in the wrong direction if I misunderstand how the `--system-site-packages` argument works. In which case the question should be, **Why does `--system-site-packages` argument not create a duplicate mirror of my system's Python packages?**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This whole system vs user python thing (and frankly, ruby and node thing) has always confused me to no end...

Comment: I posted to google's discussion board for [virtual envwrapper](https://goo.gl/1unRdp) and [Archlinux](https://goo.gl/JvNE6L). Not much interest in the first, & to me the gist of the second response was to use `pip` & not the distro's package manager. To my mind this suggests just reinstalling your required packages for each project ("memory is cheap" argument). There is zero interest in this problem. Sorry. I just muddle through it.